# Create a variable from multi step calculation in Bash

Tags: bash

I am trying to create a variable that is the output of a multi step calculation but I cannot find the correct formatting.

```sh
variableA=$(( variable1 / variable2 ) * 100)
```

When I run this get a syntax error. Can someone advise the correct formatting for above.

Additionally I would like to round `variableA` to a whole number so if anyone has a suggestion for that as well it would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put the entire expression inside [double brackets](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arithmetic-Expansion.html):

```
variableA=$(( (variable1 / variable2) * 100 ))
```

Bash only handles integer arithmetic, so if one of your variables holds a non-integer value, you’ll get a syntax error. To deal with that, you can strip everything starting with the first full stop in the value:

```
variableA=$(( (${variable1%%.*} / ${variable2%%.*}) * 100 ))
```

Comment: Sidenote: The inner brackets are not really needed for that calculation ;-)

Comment: @pLumo indeed, but I thought it useful to keep them to highlight the difference between the surrounding, syntactical brackets, and the expression itself.

Comment: sure, I meant it just as a sidenote for OP ...